# Regex in class name to identify controls

Tags: regex, winforms, desktop-application, autoit

A certain program's control ClassnameNN was identified by [AutoIt Window Information Tool](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/intro/au3spy.htm) as:

`WindowsForms10.BUTTON.app.0.24f4a7c_r27_ad19` in a previous version. In the current version it changed to:

`WindowsForms10.BUTTON.app.0.24f4a7c_r13_ad19` (notice the changes after `r`).

How to use a regular expression to solve this problem for future versions? Any workaround too is highly appreciable.

Answer (score 2):

> How to use a regular expression to solve this problem for future versions?

- [Documentation - Intro - Controls](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/intro/controls.htm) describes control selection.
- [Documentation - Intro - Window Titles and Text (Advanced)](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/intro/windowsadvanced.htm) provides an example.

Regular expression:

`WindowsForms10\.BUTTON\.app\.0\.24f4a7c_r(13|27)_ad19`

[Visual explanation](https://www.debuggex.com/r/07bMpdt2fi1FJJXj):
[image: Regular expression visualization]

Translates to ClassNN definition as:

`[TITLE:My Window; REGEXPCLASSNN:WindowsForms10\.BUTTON\.app\.0\.24f4a7c_r(13|27)_ad19]`

Change `(13|27)` to [`(\d*)`](https://www.debuggex.com/r/2y_M25DiHYfbBVNp) if any combination of digits should match (as per [AutoIt regular expressions](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/StringRegExp.htm)).

Comment: Thanks. It seems promising. I will try and get back to you.

Comment: @Abhishek_Mishra Any luck so far?