# How to do regular Expression in AutoIt Script

Tags: regex, autoit

In Autoit script Iam unable to do Regular expression for the below string Here the numbers will get changed always.

```
Actual String = _WinWaitActivate("RX_IST2_AM [PID:942564 NPID:10991 SID:498702881] sbivvrwm060.dev.ib.tor.Test.com:30000","")
```

Here the PID, NPID & SID  : will be changing  and rest of the things are always constant.

What i have tried below is

```
_WinWaitActivate("RX_IST2_AM [PID:'([0-9]{1,6})' NPID:'([0-9]{1,5})' SID:'([0-9]{1,9})' sbivvrwm060.dev.ib.tor.Test.com:30000","")
```

Can someone please help me

Comment: Related: [Regex in class name of AutoIt controls to identify the controls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30575886/regex-in-class-name-of-autoit-controls-to-identify-the-controls).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the [documentation](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/intro/windowsadvanced.htm), you should write the prefix `REGEXPTITLE:` and surround everything with square brackets, but "escape" all including ones as the dots (`.`) and spaces () with a backslash (`\`) and instead of `[0-9]` you might use `\d` like `"[REGEXPTITLE:RX_IST2_AM\ \[PID:(\d{1,6})\ NPID:(\d{1,5})\ SID:(\d{1,9})\] sbivvrwm060\.dev\.ib\.tor\.Test\.com:30000]"` as your parameter for the `Win...(...)`-Functions.

You can even omit the round brackets (`(...)`) but keep their content if you don't want to capture the content to process it further like with `StringRegExp(...)` or `StringRegExpReplace(...)` - using the `_WinWaitActivete(...)`-Function it won't make sense anyways as it is only matching and not replacing or returning anything from your regular expression.
According to [regex101](https://regex101.com/) both work, [with](https://regex101.com/r/gS1mC1/1) the round brackets and [without](https://regex101.com/r/kN9mZ6/1) - you should always use a tool like this site to confirm that your expression is actually working for your input string.

Answer (score 1):

Not familiar with autoit, but remember that regex has to completely match your string to capture results. For example, `(goat)s` will NOT capture the word `goat` if your string is `goat` or `goater`.

You have forgotten to add a `]` in your regex, so your pattern doesn't match the string and capture groups will not be extracted. Also I'm not completely sold on the usage of `'`. Based on [this](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/StringRegExp.htm) page, you can do something like `StringRegExp(yourstring, 'RX_IST2_AM [PID:([0-9]{1,6}) NPID:([0-9]{1,5}) SID:([0-9]{1,9})]', $STR_REGEXPARRAYGLOBALMATCH)` and `$1`, `$2` and `$3` would be your results respectively. But maybe your approach works too.